Is there a way to add counts to a filter in AG Grid?
We'd like to add a count of how many total results exist for a filter in the AG Grid filter toolpanel, which would be static and not change on filter selection. I've been looking at the API for filterparams as for the filter toolpanel itself with no luck.

